# How are the USB packets generated on VCOM Port (USB CDC)?

Tags: usb, usb-device

I'm trying to understand how a virtual com port sends the packets over USB. The reason behind is that I want to send packets from a PC to an MCU configured as a Communication Device Class. If I send 63 byte message with a terminal on my PC, will the MCU get a single USB packet (assuming it is configured to receive 64 bytes per packet)?

Thanks.

Comment: You may find it difficult to send 63 byte messages with a terminal program. However in a custom program, if after a pause you do a 63-byte write() to the virtual serial device and then wait a bit, then yes, there's at least a decent chance that it will show up as a single packet.  But probably no guarantee.  It depends as much on the operating system serial and serial-USB code as it does on USB itself.  Also keep in mind that serial port settings could do mapping, for example a newline might be converted to carriage return newline.

Comment: FTDI drivers have complex behaviour. They will send a packet a) when full , b) after x milliseconds , c) on magic chars like LF. It is possible the standard CDC drivers do some of the same things as they are fairly logical. Unfilled packets are padded I think - if you only send one char, you get 63 nulls